# RichEmbed is not defined error how to fix

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, embed

so, i have learn how to make a discord bot from a youtube channel which called "CodeLyon" and there is the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvvJL.png)

do someone know how to fix it? (I searched a long time for solving this problem and i didnt find anything)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Discord JS V12 it's:

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");
const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();;
```

Otherwise, it is:

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");
const Embed = new discord.RichEmbed();;
```